# Rest framework object filter based on url in viewset

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

How do i filter object based on the url? 
I followed this [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets.html) and it returns 404.

The url

```
router.register(r'api/main/search/$', restviews.SearchResult)
```

The serializers

```
class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ('name', 'categories', 'service', 'desc')
```

The view

```
class SearchResult(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    model = Listing

    def list(self, request):
        if request.QUERY_PARAMS == 'GET' and request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('sec') == '1':
            key = request.GET.get('keyword')
            queryset = Listing.objects.filter(service__name__contains=key,).distinct()
            serializer = ListingSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            content = {'Error': 'nothing to see here'}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

The logic of the view was taken from the base model view which is working correctly. So, i think it is not the query problem, more likely something else that causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be making the wrong comparison here:
`if request.QUERY_PARAMS == 'GET'`

It should be
`if request.method == 'GET'`

From the link you posted:
`you'll normally need to provide at least the queryset and serializer_class attributes.`

And also, if you look at the part of the docs about filtering - [see here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering) - you'll see that it is recommended to do the filtering in the **get_queryset** method. More precisely, you should use the part about **[Filtering against query parameters](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering#filtering-against-query-parameters)**.